# How can I restart my code from an else statement?

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement

Here I have some code I've been working on (Python 3.4) and I can't figure out how to get the program to restart after the `else` statement. I know that there is no `goto` statement.

I have tried messing about by putting the `if` statement in a `while true` loop but it just looped the `print` line and printed the output over and over again

```py
import random
    import string

    PassGen = ""

    length = int(input("how many characters would you like your password to have 8-15? "))

    if 8 <= length <=15:
        while len(PassGen) != length:
            Num1 = random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase)
            Num2 = random.choice(string.ascii_lowercase)
            Num3 = random.choice(string.digits)
            everything = [Num1, Num2, Num3]
            PassGen += random.choice(everything)
        print (PassGen)
    else:
        print ("that is an incorrect value")
```

At the moment it works perfectly fine by taking an input from the user then seeing if the input is between *8-15*. If so, it makes a password with the inner `while` loop. Otherwise, it prints the incorrect value.

Comment: you can use `While true:` loop and `break` out of the loop from `if and else statement` as needed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Asking the user for input until they give a valid response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were close. `while True` is fine, but you also need a `break` to get out of it:

```
while True:
    length = int(input("how many characters would you like in your password"))
    if 8 <= length <=15:
        while len(PassGen) != length:
            Num1 = random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase)
            Num2 = random.choice(string.ascii_lowercase)
            Num3 = random.choice(string.digits)
            everything = [Num1, Num2, Num3]
            PassGen += random.choice(everything)
        print (PassGen)
        break
    else:
        print ("that is an incorrect value")
```

Comment: this was half right I had to put the length statement inside the while loop but thanks for the help